# Sweet Alert 2 without npm

Tags: sweetalert2

My app isn't npm and I need to use Sweet Alert 2.

I looked for information on the site https://sweetalert2.github.io, but without success.

Is there any way to use Sweet Alert 2 without npm?

Regards, Felipe.

Comment: All the instructions needed to use Sweetalert2 are available at https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I had been searching hours on this topic. Don't believe it is possible to use sweetalert2 without npm.

Answer (score 1):

Just add cdn links in view:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.js"></script>
```

Js code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        Swal.fire({        
           type: 'success',
           title: 'Your work has been done',
           showConfirmButton: false,
           timer: 1500
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, just use the tag below before all javascript imports to avoid errors:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can grab it from  jsdelivr CDN put below link in the head tag

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```